# php upload file condition not working

Tags: php, file-upload

i have a page where the the visitor can upload a file, but thats not required, so in my script i put a condition if the file input (i named it 'upload') is not set or empty don't upload anything, and the file name will be equal to 'file' already existed in db; else upload it.
the problem is the condition is not working; even when i leave the input empty the upload script is executed; i know that because i get the messages that are declared in the script
here is the coded and thank you

```
    //select exercice
$ex_query = mysqli_query($link, " SELECT * FROM exercices WHERE ID = '".$exercice_ID."' ");
$exercice = mysqli_fetch_assoc($ex_query);
// --- update script if post
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    if (isset($_FILES["upload"]) && !empty($_FILES["upload"])){
        $target_dir = "docs/";
        $date_f_n = date("Y-m-d_h-i-sa");
        $file_n = basename( $_FILES["upload"]["name"]);
        $file_n = $date_f_n.$file_n;
        $target_file = $target_dir . $file_n;
        $uploadOk = 1;
        $FileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        // Check if  file is a actual image or fake image
            $check = filesize($_FILES["upload"]["tmp_name"]);
            if($check !== false) {
                $uploadOk = 1;
            } else {
                $filesizeer = "File is not an image.";
                $uploadOk = 0;
            }
         // Check file size
        if ($_FILES["upload"]["size"] > 5000000) {
            $filesizeer = "Sorry, your file is too large.";
            $uploadOk = 0;
        }
        // Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
        if ($uploadOk == 0) {
            $error = "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
        // if everything is ok, try to upload file
        } else {
             if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["upload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
            $upsuccess= "The file ". $file_n. " has been uploaded.";
            } else {
                $upfaled =  "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
            }
        }//end else upload = 0
    }else{
        $file_n = $exercice['file'];
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **FIRST** thing you have to do with an upload is check if an upload was performed AT ALL, and that it succeeded. Just because `$_FILES['foo']` exists doesn't mean the upload of this `foo` file actually succeeded.

Bare minimum checking:

```
if ($_FILES['foo']['error'] !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
   die("Upload failed with error code #" . $_FILES['foo']['error']);
}
```

or even

```
if (isset($_FILES['foo']) && etc...)
```

if you want to be really strictly correct.

If you want to allow non-uploads, but still fail on real errors, then check for the specific error codes you'd like to allow as "ok". The error codes are defined here: http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php